# UICollectionViewCell programmatically memory leak

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell` programmatically without using storyboards, but several things happening and I cannot understand why.

There is a memory leak in `BKPhotoCell`.

Cells are full screen, but when scrolling the `CollectionView`, they never reused. `Init` is called in every `indexpath.row`.

`PrepareForReuse` also never called.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        CGSize screenSize = self.view.bounds.size;
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];
        [flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
        [flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
        [flowLayout setSectionInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

        self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)  collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
        [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
        [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[BKPhotoCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BKPhotoCell"];
        [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
        [self.collectionView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    BKPhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BKPhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    return cell;
}
```

BKPhotoCell.h:

```
@interface BKPhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

BKPhotoCell.m:

```
@interface BKPhotoCell() <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic ,strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation BKPhotoCell

#define isPortrait [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown

#pragma mark - ScrollView Delegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    CGFloat offsetX = (scrollView.bounds.size.width > scrollView.contentSize.width)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    CGFloat offsetY = (scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height)?
    (scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    _imageView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                 scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);
}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
        [self.scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [self.scrollView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_scrollView];

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.bounds.size.width, self.contentView.bounds.size.height)];
        [self.imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)prepareForReuse {

    [super prepareForReuse];
    NSLog(@"Prepare for reuse");

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self.imageView  setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height)];
    // NSLog(@"Setting Content Size: %f, %f", _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);
    [_scrollView setContentSize:_imageView.image.size];

    CGFloat offsetX = (_scrollView.bounds.size.width > _scrollView.contentSize.width)?
    (_scrollView.bounds.size.width - _scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    CGFloat offsetY = (_scrollView.bounds.size.height > _scrollView.contentSize.height)?
    (_scrollView.bounds.size.height - _scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5 : 0.0;

    _imageView.center = CGPointMake(_scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                    _scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);

    float minimumZoomScale;

    if (isPortrait) {
        minimumZoomScale = _imageView.frame.size.width >= _imageView.frame.size.height ? _scrollView.frame.size.width / _imageView.frame.size.width : _scrollView.frame.size.height / _imageView.frame.size.height;
    } else {
        minimumZoomScale = _imageView.frame.size.width > _imageView.frame.size.height ? _scrollView.frame.size.width / _imageView.frame.size.width : _scrollView.frame.size.height / _imageView.frame.size.height;
    }

    [self.scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumZoomScale];
    [self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:minimumZoomScale * 2];
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:minimumZoomScale];


}
```

Comment: Use "Instruments" to exactly see at which line, which specific object is causing memory leak.

Comment: I have tried, its pointing to [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]; but I don't see whats causing it...

Comment: is self.collectionView is nil?

Comment: no sorry, I edited the code to include collectionview initialization, it was causing confusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `iOS7`  it could be you are running into a reuse bug!

I do have the same issue, it works fine on `iOS6.1` and `iOS6`, but as soon as it's started on `iOS7` (final) the cells never get reused!

I don't have a fix, I'm trying to create my own reuse logic.

Edit:

I got something working, so you need to save your attributes from the layout (maybe override `FlowLayout` if you are using it).

Then in

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
  didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell 
    forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

save your cell to a `NSMutableArray`.

in

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

check your array for cells and apply the properties e.g.:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell;

if (![_removedCells count]) {
    cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
                                                     forIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    cell = [_removedCells lastObject];
    [_removedCells removeLastObject];
    [cell prepareForReuse];        
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attr = [_layout getTempAttribute:indexPath];

    [cell setFrame: attr.frame];        
    [cell applyLayoutAttributes:attr];

    if (![cell superview]) {
        [_collectionView addSubview:cell];
    }
}
```

**getTempAttribute** just retrieves the previously calculated `position` for my `UICollectionViewCell` from the `UICollectionViewLayout`, so just a lookup by `indexPath` and returns the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, it looks as if it's working fine and `reusing` the `UICollectionViewCells` - but I can't guarantee anything ;-)

Edit2: After further testing I have to come to the conclusion that this **breaks** the rotation in the `UICollectionView`, leading to weird layout issues!

Comment: Same problem confirmed here but also for iOS 6.